# Ubuntu 14 go black screen after my video card fail

Tags: drivers, video

My video card suddenly fail while i was playing game in Windows. After that the system cannot recognize the video card. When I boot the system with Ubuntu, after passing the Ubuntu logo, it only displays a black screen with a password entering dialog. The system is still reaponing , as I can type in the password but nothing show up after that.

There is a Intel onboard display in my motherboard. I suppose the problem the problem is Ubuntu cannot automatically switch diaplay card driver to onboard display when my video card fails

I have tried
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
to uninstall the nvidia driver but it didn't work

Could anyone give me a solution ? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First reconfigure the driver:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg
```

If it isn't works, then reinstall following:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-video-all
```